# How can I execute a SP and depending on it's result execute another query which if fails should revert back what the SP has done?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I think it's a basic SQL question...sorry..new to it... :-)

I want to execute a SP inside which

```
{
```

I want to execute a SP (using EXEC) and depending on it's result I want to execute another query (`INSERT`) which if fails for any reason should revert back what the SP has done?

```
}
```

How can I do this?

Transactions? If yes, how?

**PLEASE NOTE THAT THE INNER SP SENDS A MAIL.**

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @rc int

EXEC @rc = EXEC inner_proc

IF (@rc = 1)
   INSERT something

IF @@ERROR <> 0
    ROLLBACK
ELSE
    COMMIT
```

Comment: What if the inner_proc sends mail to someone?? Would it get rollbacked too??

Comment: Seriously, though, the best way to handle this would probably be to queue mails in a database table and have a background process load them up and send them. Then the insert for the mail would be rolled back in this scenario.